# Regex static group problem

Tags: java, regex

I have several strings in the rough form:

[some number with one or 2 digits] [some text] [a text which is ABC or BC] [some text]

```
String test = "12testABCtest";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([\\d]{1,2})([\\w]*)(ABC|BC)([\\w]*)");
```

But it gives me always "BC in the 3rd group instead of ABC. ( as it include the A in the previous group )

Do you have any idea how to do it?

thank you,

Comment: Instead of `[\\d]` you can just write `\\d`, same goes for `\\w`. `(ABC|BC)` can be written `(A?BC)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make the text match non-greedy:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([\\d]{1,2})([\\w]*?)(A?BC)([\\w]*)");
```

**Reference:**

```
Reluctant quantifiers
-----------------------------
X??     X, once or not at all
X*?     X, zero or more times
X+?     X, one or more times
```

**Source:** [`Pattern` javadoc: Reluctant quantifiers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#reluc)

Basically: reluctant quantifiers will match as little as possible, as opposed to the default greedy quantifiers that will match as much as possible. You get a reluctant quantifier by appending a `?` to another quantifier.